# Display message on non-stop thread

Tags: android, multithreading

Following code is within an android activity class.
The project required a non-stop thread when apps is active and stop when apps is inActive/closed.

I predicted to see a non-stop "Hello World" message display in logCat.However I **only** saw **one-times** Hello World messgae .
What wrong of my code,so that I able to see a non-stop "Hello World"

Hope someone advice. Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.e("onStart","beforeStart");
    new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    Log.e("onStart","Start");
    this.pickButtonThread();

}
    private void pickButtonThread(){
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
                    // code runs in a thread
                    PickerItemActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                    public void run() {
                         // code runs in a UI(main) thread
                         //isPickButtonEnableDisable();
                         //new HttpRequestTask().execute();
                         Log.e("pickButtonThread", "Hello World");

                    }
                 });
               } catch (final Exception ex) {
           }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you don't have any loop inside your `run()` method, thus it's run just once and it exits. However, declaring an endless loop is not considered a good idea as `Android OS` might kill it if there's lack of memory.

You could use a `Handler` using the `.postDelayed()` method to post messages every X seconds.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Log.e("pickButtonThread", "Hello World");
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);         // Every second
  }
};
```